How to make a beautiful smooth edge between two joined meshes, after using bool tool ? See image
How do I make a beautiful smooth edge between two joined meshes, using dyntopo and then bool tool union ?
The results often get rough and bumpy when I smooth out the finished result, where the two have been joined, like I’m showing on the image here. I always go over the joined areas with the dyntopo clay brush at 0 in order to make the mesh more even. It almost always turns out quite rough and bumpy.
Is there a way to avoid it and make it beautiful and more seamlessly smooth?

And this is the wireframe of that same area of the object


Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see How to take a screenshot. Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.
